# Sharepoint 2010 Breadcrumb not showing sub folders in document library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, breadcrumb

I have a document library with folders in it.  I want to view the document library through a custom Site Page shown below and be able to use the Sharepoint Foundation 2010 breadcrumb in the left corner of the ribbon to navigate/see the folder structure of my library.  Here is the Site Page:

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
    Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <span class="content-page-top-span">
        <div class="list-header">
            <span>Test Execution Tools</span>
        </div>
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Left" Title="loc:Left" PartChromeType="None">
            <ZoneTemplate>            
            </ZoneTemplate>
        </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
    </span>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the excerpt from the elements.xml for the module that deploys it

```
<File Path="Pages\Document List Pages\TestExecutionTools.aspx" Url="TestExecutionTools.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/TestExecutionTools" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="Left"/>
    </File>
```

The document library itself is custom...here is the schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="DocumentList" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="DocumentList" BaseType="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x0101">
        <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" />
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="Description"/>
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" Hidden="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title"></Field>
      <Field ID="{4b1bf6c6-4f39-45ac-acd5-16fe7a214e5e}" Type="Text" Name="TemplateUrl" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Template_Link;" XName="TemplateUrl" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" PITarget="mso-infoPathSolution" PIAttribute="href" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="TemplateUrl"></Field>
      <Field ID="{cd1ecb9f-dd4e-4f29-ab9e-e9ff40048d64}" Type="Text" Name="xd_ProgID" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Html_File_Link;" XName="ProgID" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="xd_ProgID"></Field>
      <Field ID="{fbf29b2d-cae5-49aa-8e0a-29955b540122}" Type="Boolean" Group="_Hidden" Name="xd_Signature" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="xd_Signature" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Xml_signed;" XName="{FBF29B2D-CAE5-49aa-8E0A-29955B540122}" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE"></Field>
      <Field ID="{D815C45C-737A-4914-931E-B37452A73D54}" Type="Text" Name="Description" Hidden="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInFileDlg="TRUE" DisplayName="Description" StaticName="Description"/>
      <Field ID="{e52012a0-51eb-4c0c-8dfb-9b8a0ebedcb6}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="Combine" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Merge;" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Combine">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
          <FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl" />
          <FieldRef Name="TemplateUrl" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{5d36727b-bcb2-47d2-a231-1f0bc63b7439}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="RepairDocument" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Relink;" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="RepairDocument">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
          <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE" FreeForm="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,Add_New_Document)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,MoreDocuments)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,All_Documents;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="True" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Url="Forms/AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Description"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="2" Type="HTML" FileDialog="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,File_Dialog_View;" Hidden="TRUE" Path="filedlg.htm" ModerationType="Moderator">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="BaseName"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor" TextOnly="TRUE"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified" TextOnly="TRUE"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="3" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Explorer_View;" TabularView="FALSE" Url="Forms/WebFldr.aspx" SetupPath="pages\webfldr.aspx" RequiresClientIntegration="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
        <ViewFields />
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="6" Type="HTML" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="7" AggregateView="TRUE" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Merge_Documents;" TabularView="FALSE" ToolbarTemplate="MergeToolBar" DefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Url="Forms/Combine.aspx" Hidden="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Combine"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="9" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Relink_Documents;" ToolbarTemplate="RelinkToolBar" TabularView="FALSE" DefaultView="FALSE" Url="Forms/repair.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Hidden="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="RepairDocument"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ContentType"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="TemplateUrl"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
          <Where>
            <Neq>
              <FieldRef Name="xd_Signature" />
              <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
            </Neq>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="40" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="assetLibTemp" DefaultView="FALSE" MobileView="FALSE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Url="Forms/Thumbnails.aspx" Hidden="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <RowLimit>20</RowLimit>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/DispForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/EditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Forms/Upload.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewFormDialog" Path="EditDlg.htm">
        <ListFormOpening>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = new OWSForm(]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <Switch>
              <Expr>
                <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
              </Expr>
              <Case Value="">
                <HTML><![CDATA[OWSForm]]></HTML>
              </Case>
              <Default>
                <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
              </Default>
            </Switch>
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[, false, ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <HttpVDir />
            <HTML>/_layouts/</HTML>
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[);
</script>
]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[ frm.dopt.chDateSep = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="29" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.chTimeSep = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="30" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.SetTimeFormat(]]></HTML>
          <ProjectProperty Select="Time24" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[); frm.dopt.SetDateOrder(]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="33" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[); frm.dopt.SetDOW(]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="4108" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[); frm.dopt.stAM = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="40" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.stPM = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="41" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.TimeMarkPosn = ]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="4101" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.webTZOffsetMin = ]]></HTML>
          <ProjectProperty Select="TimeZoneBias" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[; ]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[ frm.nopt.chDigSep = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="15" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.chDecimal = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="14" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.chMinus = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="81" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.iNegNumber = ]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="4112" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.SetGrouping(]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="16" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[); ]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
frm.stFieldPrefix = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <FieldPrefix />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[;
frm.stImagesPath = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>/_layouts/images/</ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[;
frm.wBaseType = ]]></HTML>
          <ListProperty Select="BaseType" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[;
</script>]]></HTML>
          <Switch>
            <Expr>
              <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
            </Expr>
            <Case Value="">
              <HTML><![CDATA[<form name="OWSForm" id="OWSForm" EncType="multipart/form-data" Action="]]></HTML>
              <HttpPath />
              <HTML><![CDATA[" Method=POST onSubmit="return false;">]]></HTML>
            </Case>
          </Switch>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<input type="Hidden" name="_charset_" value="utf-8">
<input id="onetidCmd" type="Hidden" name="Cmd" value="Save">
<input id="onetidIsFormValid" type="hidden" name="IsFormValid">
<input id="onetidFormWasPosted" type="hidden" name="FormWasPosted">
<input id="MustUpdateForm" type="hidden" name="MustUpdateForm" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="NextID" id="NextID" value="-1">
<input type="hidden" name="NextUsing" id="NextUsing" value="]]></HTML>
          <GetVar Name="Source" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[">
]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<span id='part1'>]]></HTML>
          <Identity />
        </ListFormOpening>
        <ListFormBody>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<script type="text/javascript">var _g_tp_fNewForm = true;</script>
]]></HTML>
          <Fields>
            <Switch>
              <Expr>
                <Property Select="Name" />
              </Expr>
              <Case Value="FileLeafRef">
                <SetVar Name="ShowField" Scope="Request">0</SetVar>
              </Case>
              <Default>
                <SetVar Name="ShowField" Scope="Request">1</SetVar>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<tr style="display:none"><th nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><nobr>]]></HTML>
                <Property Select="DisplayName" HTMLEncode="TRUE" AutoNewLine="TRUE" />
                <Switch>
                  <Expr>
                    <Property Select="Required" />
                  </Expr>
                  <Case Value="TRUE">
                    <HTML><![CDATA[<font color=red> *</font>]]></HTML>
                    <SetVar Scope="Request" Name="HasRequired">TRUE</SetVar>
                  </Case>
                  <Default>
                    <HTML><![CDATA[<font color=red></font>]]></HTML>
                  </Default>
                </Switch>
                <HTML><![CDATA[</nobr></th><td class="ms-formbody">]]></HTML>
                <Field />
                <Switch>
                  <Expr>
                    <Property Select="RichText" />
                  </Expr>
                  <Case Value="TRUE" />
                  <Default>
                    <Switch>
                      <Expr>
                        <Property Select="Type" />
                      </Expr>
                      <Case Value="Choice" />
                      <Case Value="MultiChoice" />
                      <Default>
                        <HTML><![CDATA[&#160;]]></HTML>
                        <Switch>
                          <Expr>
                            <Property Select="NoEditFormBreak" />
                          </Expr>
                          <Case Value="TRUE" />
                          <Default>
                            <HTML><![CDATA[<br>]]></HTML>
                          </Default>
                        </Switch>
                      </Default>
                    </Switch>
                  </Default>
                </Switch>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<span class="ms-formdescription">]]></HTML>
                <Property Select="Description" HTMLEncode="TRUE" AutoHyperLink="TRUE" AutoNewLine="TRUE" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[</span></td></tr>]]></HTML>
              </Default>
            </Switch>
          </Fields>
          <HTML><![CDATA[</table>]]></HTML>
          <Switch>
            <Expr>
              <GetVar Name="HasRequired" />
            </Expr>
            <Case Value="TRUE">
              <HTML><![CDATA[
          <table border="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr>
            <td id="reqdFldTxt" class="ms-descriptiontext" colspan="2" height="150px" valign="top"><br><font color=red>*</font> 
             &#160;]]></HTML>
              <HTML HTMLEncode="TRUE">$Resources:core,webview_editdlg_required_field;</HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[
            </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          ]]></HTML>
            </Case>
          </Switch>
          <ContentTypes>
            <IfSubString>
              <Expr1>0x0120</Expr1>
              <Expr2>
                <Property Select="ID" />
              </Expr2>
              <Then>
                <HTML><![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
            _tp_rgctfld = new Array;
            _g_tp_rgcts.push(_tp_rgctfld);
            var fldct = frmCurrent.FindField("ContentType");
            if (fldct != null)
                fldct.AddChoice(]]></HTML>
                <ScriptQuote>
                  <Property Select="Name" />
                </ScriptQuote>
                <HTML><![CDATA[);
            </script>
            ]]></HTML>
              </Then>
              <Else>
                <HTML><![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var fldct = frmCurrent.FindField("ContentType");
            if (fldct != null)
                fldct.AddChoice(]]></HTML>
                <ScriptQuote>
                  <Property Select="Name" />
                </ScriptQuote>
                <HTML><![CDATA[);
            _tp_rgctfld = new Array;            
            ]]></HTML>
                <ForEach Select="FieldRefs/FieldRef">
                  <HTML>
                _tp_ctfld = new Object(null);
                _tp_ctfld.stName=</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="Name" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>;
                _tp_ctfld.fRequired = BoolFromString(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="Required" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>);
                _tp_ctfld.fHidden = BoolFromString(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="Hidden" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>);
                _tp_ctfld.fShowInNewForm = BoolFromString2(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ShowInNewForm" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>, true);
                _tp_ctfld.fShowInEditForm = BoolFromString2(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ShowInEditForm" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>, true);
                _tp_ctfld.fShowInFileDlg = BoolFromString2(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ShowInFileDlg" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>, true);                
                _tp_ctfld.fReadOnly = BoolFromString(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ReadOnly" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>);
                _tp_ctfld.stDisplay =</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="DisplayName" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>;</HTML>
                  <ForEach Select="Default">
                    <HTML>
                    _tp_ctfld.stDefault=</HTML>
                    <ScriptQuote>
                      <Property Select="." />
                    </ScriptQuote>
                    <HTML>;</HTML>
                  </ForEach>
                  <HTML>
                    _tp_rgctfld.push(_tp_ctfld);
                </HTML>
                </ForEach>
                <HTML><![CDATA[
            _g_tp_rgcts.push(_tp_rgctfld);
            </script>
            ]]></HTML>
              </Else>
            </IfSubString>
          </ContentTypes>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
var fldct = frmCurrent.FindField("ContentType");
if (fldct != null)
    fldct.BuildUI();
</script>
]]></HTML>
        </ListFormBody>
        <ListFormClosing>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
</span>]]></HTML>
          <Switch>
            <Expr>
              <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
            </Expr>
            <Case Value="">
              <HTML><![CDATA[</form>]]></HTML>
            </Case>
          </Switch>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
]]></HTML>
        </ListFormClosing>
      </Form>
    </Forms>
    <DefaultDescription>$Resources:core,camlidDc5;</DefaultDescription>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

The problem is that when i navigate into the folders of the document library the Breadcrumb does not change to show the folder structure.  The kicker is that when i access the AllItems.aspx page for the document library the breadcrumb works just fine...navigate several levels in and the breadcrumb shows you where you are with hyperlinks to move around.  What is wrong with my site page...i have looked at AllItems.aspx and honestly am stumped...Help is appreciated.  (NOTE this is on Sharepoint FOUNDATION)

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour you are seeing is correct.

The breadcrumb (and, indeed, all the navigation controls in SharePoint) use classes called ['Navigation Providers'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558975.aspx) (a.k.a. 'Site Map Providers') to give the navigation controls a model of the Site Collection they're in. They're standard ASP.NET technology actually, though SharePoint has a number of these providers that were written specifically for it, and that it uses.

What's happening is that the standard navigation providers that were written for SharePoint were written to understand the concepts of Sites, subsites, libraries and folders. They can determine this information from the URL.

However, your solution only has 1 page, and the navigation providers only see it as one page. You're adding a ListView web part to it, but when you're using that to view sub folders, etc., you're still **on the same page**. On your web part page, going into a folder is not changing the page. Thus, the breadcrumb doesn't change. I know that that is the same as ListView in a document library, but as I said, the navigation providers understand document libraries and treat them differently.

A related issue is that if you have two ListView web parts on the same page, which one should control the breadcrumb?

You can write your own Navigation Providers, and this isn't too complicated (so you might  be able to achieve something that way), but actually I don't see how you can avoid problems if there are two ListViews on page.

Thus, what you're seeing is correct out of the box, and may be difficult to implement yourself due to the issue of multiple ListView web parts.

Answer (score 0):

http://geekswithblogs.net/PointsToShare/archive/2012/01/06/the-disappearing-and-reappearing-list-ribbon-again.aspx

Try this...

Comment: Not what i'm looking for